# ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-11.10

I have MySQL installed on Ubuntu 11.10. I has been working fine for months but yesterday I started getting the following message

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

and cannot get rid of it. I tried

```
/etc/init.d/mysqld start
```

and got

```
bash: /etc/init.d/mysqld: No such file or directory
```

The /etc/init.d/ directory contains mysql but not mysqld. I tried

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

It just hung for about half an hour and then I ctrl-C-ed it. I then tried

```
sudo service mysql start
```

I got

```
mysql start/running
```

But when I tried

```
mysql
```

I got

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

I tried

```
ps aux|grep mysql
```

and got

```
peter    17754  0.0  0.0   4196   768 pts/1    S+   09:38   0:00 grep --color=auto mysql
```

I ideas about fixing this problem would be most appreciated.

Comment: What does the log say? This is off-topic here, as it is not a programming question.

Comment: /var/log/mysql.err is empty

Comment: Seems like mysqld isn't running. Does `/var/log/messages` give something useful?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the standard mysql.log file? Possibly called mysqld.log.

It could be that you're out of disk space, would explain the sudden problem, try:

```
$ df -h
```

Look at the 4th column "Avail"

Comment: Remember df -i for inodes, too, which can behave just like a full disk, without using up space.If all else fails, I might even try an strace so that I would have some info to go in.